# C# network setup for XNA video game

Tags: c#, networking, xna

So I'm building a little game for a small project that will have a server and 4 clients, one of which will be on the server pc. The problem I'm having is finding a good tutorial for setting up server/client connections. The one I DID find was
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObcGBT4ZWEU

But when I try to use it in my XNA game, I get errors saying is a 'field' but is used like a 'type' with 
        `sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);`

The overall portion looks like this. I've cut out the bottom part because it doesn't partain.

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        List<string> receiveMsgs = new List<string>();
        Socket sck;
        EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        string localip = GetLocalIP();
        string friendsIp = GetLocalIP();

        public Game1()
        {
```

If anyone has any good tutorials on how to do what I'm trying to do, it would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you move `sck.SetSocketOption(...)` into the constructor?

Comment: Oh and init `sck` on the same line you declare it.

Comment: You can try and use Lidgren Network Engine if you don't want to mess with it yourself, and assuming you are building to windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot answer to the first part of your question, I am not good enough for that. But I had to do a Game at school with a Network(Windows game). I used XNA and Lindgren, and I found this tutorial which was pretty well done, and not too complicated. The only thing is that it only gives you the final .sln file and not a step-by-step explanation. But since I finally managed to use it, you should be able too and I could maybe help you if you have any question.

http://xnacoding.blogspot.fr/2010/07/how-to-lidgren-network.html

direct file: http://www.mediafire.com/download/t32ymzztctm/GameNetworkingExample.zip

Good luck with you project !

Comment: I can't give you any upvote, but thanks for the answer.